# Creating a graph of frequency of a specific word from a dataframe over a time period in R

Tags: r, twitter, data-science, data-mining, text-mining

I have a dataframe of tweets in R, looking like this:

```
  tweet_text                                              tweet_time          rdate        twt
  <chr>                                                   <dttm>              <date>     <dbl>
1 No New England cottage is complete without nautical t.. 2016-08-25 09:21:00 2016-08-25     1
2 Justice Scalia spent his last hours with members of co… 2016-11-24 16:28:00 2016-11-24     1
3 WHAT THE FAILED OKLAHOMA ABORTION BILL TELLS US http:/… 2016-11-24 16:27:00 2016-11-24     1
4 Bipartisan bill in US Senate to restrict US arms sales… 2016-10-26 07:03:00 2016-10-26     1
5 #MustResign campaign is underway with the heat p his S… 2016-10-01 08:15:00 2016-10-01     1
```

Each tweet has a specific date assigned, all tweets in the dataframe are from a period of one year. I want to find out a frequency of one specific word ("Senate" for example) over the entire period and plot a graph capturing how the frequency changed over time. I am fairly new to R and I could only think of super complicated ways to do it, but I am sure there must be some that's really easy and simple.

I appreciate any suggestions.

Comment: How about using `stringr::str_detect` or `stringr::str_detect_all` to detect if the word appears in the text, and aggregate the counts per period you want.

Comment: [See here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example) on making an R question that folks can help with. That includes a sample of data that recreates the issue, all necessary code, and a clear explanation of what you've tried and what hasn't worked.

Answer (score 1):

```
textFreq <- function(pattern, text){
    freq <- gregexpr(pattern = pattern, text = text, ignore.case = TRUE)
    freq <- lapply(freq, FUN = function(x){
            if(length(x)==1&&x==-1){
                return(0)
            } else {
                return(length(x))
            }
        })
    freq <- unlist(freq)
    return(freq)
}

test.text <- c("senate.... SENate.. sen","Working in the senate...", "I like dogs")
textFreq(pattern = "senate", test.text)
# [1] 2 1 0
```

you can use `dplyr` to group by time periods and use mutate

```
library(dplyr)
library(magrittr)
data <- data %>% 
    group_by(*somedatefactor*) %>% #if you wanted to aggrigate every 10 days or something
    mutate(SenateFreqPerTweet = textFreq(pattern = "Senate", text = tweet_text),
           SenateFreqTotal = sum(SenateFreqPerTweet)) #Counts sum based on current grouping
```

You may even wrap the previous statement into another function. To do so check out [programming with dplyr](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/dplyr/vignettes/programming.html)

But regardless, using this approach you can easily plot the `SenateFreqTotal` with `ggplot2` package

```
 data2 <- data %>% #may be helpful to reduce the size of the dataframe before plotting.
     select(SenateFreqTotal, *somedatefactor*) %>% 
     distinct()
 ggplot(data2, aes(y=SenateFreqTotal, x = *somedatefactor*)+ geom_bar(stat="identity")
```

if you do not want to aggregate the frequencies you can just plot like so

```
ggplot(data, aes(y=SenateFreqPerTweet, x = tweet_time)) + 
    geom_bar(stat = "identity")
```

Comment: see the first and second code block of my answer to see how the function `textFreq` operates. It takes a character vector and returns an integer vector counting the number of times it detects a provided pattern. I'm not sure I understand your question.